# How to configure nginx.conf and php-fpm using brew servinces in MAC-OS in order to run php?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, mac, 502-error

I have following logs in php-fpm log .

```
[19-Jan-2020 15:09:33] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[19-Jan-2020 15:09:33] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[19-Jan-2020 15:09:33] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[19-Jan-2020 15:09:33] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[19-Jan-2020 15:09:33] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 11067
[19-Jan-2020 15:09:33] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

Here is Nginx.conf file :

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8888;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
           # fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;

            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```

I am trying to run phpinfo() function , Its gives me error 502 . 
Notes: I am using php@7.2 and php-fpm 7.2  , I already changed user and group in php-fpm.conf file , Any help will be appreciated .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Is this a developer machine? If so, why not spawning a [local php web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Nginx as a proxy, all your PHP request will be proxied to your apache web server, in this case, you need to check your apache config also check is your apache is using php7-fpm. In this link, you will find information about [Apache2 and PHP-FPM](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-run-apache2-with-php7-2-fpm-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/).

In this tutorial, you can find a way to set up your PHP-FPM to solve the Notice in your logs about the USER directive is ignored. [PHP-FPM Set up](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/serve-php-php-fpm-and-nginx/)